# macOS freeze - How to find faulty software or system crash logs?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, crash, performance

For 6 months now my Mac freezes 4 to 5 times a week, forcing me to reboot.

The software I run the most when my Mac freezes are: Google Chrome and Molotov.tv.

I don't notice anything wrong in Activity Monitor (no processor burn) BUT the fans begin to accelerate, and gradually, nothing reacts. I am then forced to stop the machine by pressing 5 seconds on the power button.

I don't know how to find the faulty software (or the daemon), can you help me ?

**Config:**

- MacBook Pro 2014 15"
- 2.5 GHz
- 16 GB RAM
- macOS Sierra 10.12.6

Comment: i would start by downloading the app Temperature Guage 4.1 and see what parts of the computer are heating up if any.  Could be a faulty sensor.

Comment: Is there anything you've discovered you can do that will definitely bring on the problem? In other words, is there something you know you can do that will cause your Mac to freeze? This would help in terms of troubleshooting. Also, can you recall anything you did six months ago that coincides with this problem (e.g. new hardware, new software, etc)?